# Vue Cli 3 -typescript how to use @Prop() with two way binding?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, prop, two-way-binding

My source code is:

**Child Component:**

```
<template>
  <v-snackbar
    v-model="showSnackbar"
    :bottom="y === 'bottom'"
    :left="x === 'left'"
    :multi-line="mode === 'multi-line'"
    :right="x === 'right'"
    :timeout="timeout"
    :top="y === 'top'"
    :vertical="mode === 'vertical'"
  >
    {{ text }}
    <v-btn
      color="pink"
      flat
      @click="showSnackbar = false"
    >
      Close
    </v-btn>
  </v-snackbar>
</template>

export default class AliUMSSnackbar extends Vue {
  @Prop() private showSnackbar!: Boolean;
}
```

**Parent component:**

```
<ali-snackbar v-bind:showSnackbar="showSnackbar"></ali-snackbar>
```

But on clicking Close button, getting this error '[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "showSnackbar"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Vue `2.3.0+`, you can use the [`.sync modifier`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) to have a  "two-way binding" for a prop.

This can be done by emitting events in the pattern of `update:myPropName`.

So in your child component, update the prop on button click by doing this.

```
<v-btn color="pink" flat @click="() => this.$emit('update:showSnackbar', false)">Close</v-btn>
```

And modify your parent component to the one below so it can listen to the emitted event and update a local data property which is `showSnackbar`.

`<ali-snackbar v-bind:showSnackbar.sync="showSnackbar"></ali-snackbar>`